# Facebook Graph API Explorer: posting link doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I'm trying to post a link via Graph API Explorer, I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request.",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

But when I visit the page, the link seems to be posted

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: BTW: If I try the same with a message instead of a link, it works fine

Comment: If it get posted but you get an error file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs